# pyhoton dict and list, I did most of work need some assistance

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. The program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).

Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt, separating multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;). Next, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file

```
Ex: If the input is:

file1.txt
and the contents of file1.txt are:

20
Gunsmoke
30
The Simpsons
10
Will & Grace
14
Dallas
20
Law & Order
12
Murder, She Wrote
```

the file output_keys.txt should contain:

```
10: Will & Grace
12: Murder, She Wrote
14: Dallas
20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order
30: The Simpsons
```

and the file output_titles.txt should contain:

```
Dallas
Gunsmoke
Law & Order
Murder, She Wrote
The Simpsons
Will & Grace
```

Note: There is a newline at the end of each output file.

This is the code I have so far

```
def readFile(filename):
    my_dict = {}

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:

       lines = infile.readlines()

       for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):
                 if lines[index].strip()=='':continue

       count = int(lines[index].strip())

       name = lines[index + 1].strip()

       if count in my_dict.keys():

           name_list = my_dict.get(count)

           name_list.append(name)

       else:

           my_dict[count] = [name]

       print(count,name)
    return my_dict
```

I get this error

```
Program output displayed here
(Your program produced no output)
```

can you help me make this function correctly?

Comment: Try to use the return statement inside the function. You gave the return statement outside the function

Comment: Also do proper indentation.

Comment: will you edit my code and post that in the correct format, I am sorry to ask I don't know how to do that.  Ib will upvote and ask for people to upvote if it works as well

Comment: if you absolutely need help with formatting, use IDEs such as PyCharm and use the formatting tools to help.

Comment: Also, it's a *really* bad idea to use `dict` as a variable name...

Answer (score 0):

There is lack of indentation and return statements are outside the function

```
def readFile(filename):
    dict = {}

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:

       lines = infile.readlines()

       for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):
                 if lines[index].strip()=='':continue

       count = int(lines[index].strip())

       name = lines[index + 1].strip()

       if count in dict.keys():

           name_list = dict.get(count)

           name_list.append(name)

       else:

           dict[count] = [name]

       print(count,name)
    return dict
```

Comment: I get this error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in <module>
    output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)
  File "main.py", line 31, in output_keys
    for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
TypeError: descriptor 'keys' of 'dict' object needs an argument

Comment: you use dict as a variable, you can change it into my_dict or something instead of dict and check again.

Comment: refer to what @tim had said in your question, rename your variable to something else, as the similar named variable will confuse python compiler with the original class.

Comment: when I did that, I get (Your program produced no output)

Comment: can u clarify on that part, what do you mean by no results? can u include a screenshot so that we can help

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your question is edited. Since you are implementing dictionary function, when you declare mydict, u need to assign the function to it. eg: my_dict = dict()

Comment: Your current declaration my_dict = {} should work as well, but we need to see the whole code to understand what is missing